# Windows 7 Taskbar explorer.exe shortcut open to a custom library location

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, taskbar

I want to change the default start location of the Windows Explorer shortcut that is pinned to my Windows 7 Taskbar to be a custom library I created.

**Here's what I've tried:**

In my Libraries directory I removed everything except for the "Documents" library and the "Custom" library that I created.  I noticed that when you're in the custom library in Windows Explorer, the address bar shows `Libraries\Custom`, so in the Properties of the `explorer.exe` shortcut I tried adding that path, but that didn't work.

It seems like I could probably use the "Custom" library's GUID to open up that directory by default, but I don't know where to find the GUID for this custom library I created.

Does anyone know how I can get the taskbar shortcut to open up my custom library by default?

Answer (score 0):

You can change Windows Explorer's default behavior to open your custom library as follows:

1. Navigate to the folder where your custom library's definition file is saved by pasting the following path into the address bar of  Windows Explorer:

   ```
   %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries
   ```
2. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right-click your custom library file then choose **Copy as path** on the context menu
3. On the Windows Taskbar (1) Right-click the Windows Explorer icon, (2) Right-click **Windows Explorer** on the jump menu, then (3) click **Properties**:

   [image]
4. In the *Target:* text box **add a space** after the existing text of `%windir%\explorer.exe`, paste the path you copied in step 2, then click **OK**

Check out [this article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/239258/win_ex_default.html) for other options for customizing Explorer's start location (although it doesn't explain how to use a custom library as we've done here).